# How to remove bottom bar from NavigationView/TableView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, interface-builder

I have an app that has a TableView, NavigationView and TabBar running together.
There is a bar along the bottom of the screen above the TabBar that looks exactly like the NavigationBar at the top of the screen.  I have no idea what it is or how to get rid of it.
Here is what it looks like with what I want gone crossed out:
[alt text http://www.jamespwright.com/images/public/tabandnavigationview.jpg](http://www.jamespwright.com/images/public/tabandnavigationview.jpg)

This is the structure of the Views:
[alt text http://www.jamespwright.com/images/public/tableviewstructure.jpg](http://www.jamespwright.com/images/public/tableviewstructure.jpg)

Any idea what it is and how to get rid of it?
It stays there when I navigate to my next view which is just a plain old View, nothing special except that it displays some labels.

Comment: Why is there no UITableView under your CitiesTableViewController?  The NIB tree structure you're showing doesn't seem to match your screenshot.  

Anyway, UITableView can have header and footer views (`tableHeaderView` and `tableFooterView`).  The UITableView in your screen shot appears to have a `tableFooterView`; Your nib doesn't appear to have any UITableView at all.

Comment: I honestly don't know exactly where the UITableView is coming from.
I am still new to this and I followed an old tutorial.
I do know that I have a separate CityTableView.xib file that is run by CityTableViewController and within that Controller is al the code for populating the TableView.  However, I don't know where that tableview is defined exactly, nor can I figure out how to change its properties.

Comment: I have updated the code.  There is now a UITableView under the CitiesTableViewController with both the Datasource and Delegate set to CitiesTableViewController.  I don't know if it's the right way to do things, but it works as it did before.  Only it still displays that footer (or Toolbar if Jordan below is correct).  I still don't know how to get rid of it either way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES];
```

Here's more of an example:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application 
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,480)] autorelease];
    RootViewController *rootViewController = [[[RootViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped] autorelease];
    self.navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController] autorelease];
    navigationController.toolbarHidden = YES;

    [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Comment: Edit answer to provide more of an example. Jordan

Answer (score 0):

In Interface Builder under Table View Attributes (which you can find under Tools / Attributes Inspector), the third section is "Simulated User Interface Attributes". The last option is "Bottom Bar". Set it to None.

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the answer because of haj1000's advice.  That got me looking around the properties in Interface Builder and I noticed that when I clicked on the 2nd tab in the Tab Bar (which is set to a NavigationController rather than a ViewController) there was an option for "Shows Toolbar" that was checked.  I turned that off and it worked.
So Jordan's advice was correct, but I have no idea where to put Jordan's code in the application.